# Dirac spinors completeness relation for $d>4$

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices

In $d=4$ and in the rest mass frame, the four Dirac spinors $u_s(0)$ and $v_s(0)$ satisfy the completeness relation
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{2} u_s(0) \overline{u}_s(0) - \sum_{s=1}^{2}  v_s(0) \overline{v}_s(0) = \textbf{1}\,.
$$
This relation is intuitive for me because we have four complex vectors of four components which are forming a complete basis for the $4$ dimensional matrices of the $C\ell(4)$ Clifford algebra. On the other hand, for $d>4$ we still have four spinors as solutions of the Dirac equation, so I guess the completeness relation for $d>4$ should look something like
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{2} u_s(0) \overline{u}_s(0) - \sum_{s=1}^{2}  v_s(0) \overline{v}_s(0) = P\,.
$$
where $P$ is some projector different from the identity, since we don't have enough basis vectors now to construct the $2^{d/2}$ dimensional matrices corresponding to the same $C\ell(4)$ algebra in the higher dimensional representation.

My question is, is this correct? And where can I find some literature on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say we still have four spinors as solutions of the Dirac equation when $d>4$? (I assume you mean four *linearly independent* solutions, because of course the Dirac equation has infinitely many solutions even when $d=4$, just not all linearly independent.) For any $d$, the number of linearly independent Dirac spinors is the same as the number of components of a Dirac spinor. For example, with $d=6$, a Dirac spinor has 8 components, and a complete basis necessarily has 8 different Dirac spinors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So my assumption is that the representation I use for the Dirac matrices does not change the physics, i.e. whatever dimension I choose for the Dirac matrices I should still have four linearly independent solutions for the electron. Is this not correct?

Comment: I assume that you're using the symbol $d$ for the number of spacetime dimensions. If you keep $d=4$ and only change the representation, then you still have four linearly independent solutions, because you still have four linearly independent Dirac matrices $\gamma^\mu$ no matter how they're represented. But in $d=2$ dimensions, you only have $2$ linearly independent Dirac matrices (say $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^1$) and only two linearly independent solutions to the Dirac equation. You can probably find more information by searching for keywords like "Clifford algebra matrix representations."

Comment: So what you're saying is that I cannot increase the dimensionality of the Dirac matrices and still keep d=4 and four spinor solutions? I thought different representations also included different dimensionalities since I can alway embed a matrix in a higher dimensional one.

Comment: You can increase the size of the matrices used in the representation without changing the number $d$ of spacetime dimensions. That doesn't affect the number of linearly independent Dirac spinors. But changing $d$ is not a matter of changing the representation, it's a matter of changing the number of $\gamma^\mu$s regardless of the representation. Example: if $d=4$ or $d=6$, you can use matrices of size $8\times 8$ in both cases, but in $d=4$, you only have four $\gamma^\mu$s and four linearly independent spinors, while in $d=6$ you have six $\gamma^\mu$s and six linearly independent spinors.

Comment: Maybe it helps to forget about spinors for a moment and just think about ordinary vectors. You can use a 17-component representation for vectors in 3d space, if you want to, but only three of them can be linearly independent. In 17-dimensional space, 17 of them are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you very much, this cleared all my misunderstandings!